# Why a WCF DataService app fails because of System.Web.Mvc 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, wcf-data-services

We have installed .NET 4.5.1 on some servers, and suddenly a legacy WCF Data Service application fails with the following error:

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/GranittService/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\GranittService\bin Calling assembly : System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\GranittService\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/granittservice/573ec422/2e9e1d06/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/granittservice/573ec422/2e9e1d06/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/GranittService/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/GranittService/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/granittservice/573ec422/2e9e1d06/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/granittservice/573ec422/2e9e1d06/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/GranittService/bin/System.Web.Mvc.EXE. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/GranittService/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.

Note that the calling assembly is System.Web. Yes, WCF Data Service depends on System.Web, but System.Web doesn't depend on System.Web.Mvc, neiter does other assemblies our service uses (this is a fairly basic WCF Data Service app exposing a database as OData feed). What can require System.Web.Mvc?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your web.config for assemblyBinding redirects to a version of MVC which isn't installed (4.0, in your case):
/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

If you don't need MVC, you could try removing the config elements, or any MVC references in your project and see if it builds (and tests).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have this section and the project didn't use System.Web.Mvc, so the presence of this section didn't change anything. As a workaround I included Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc NuGet package in my project, and then it worked. But I am still puzzled why it was required because it's not referenced either directly or indirectly.